# How to add child fragment without ActionBar and swipe to class fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have Fragment `MainActivity` class with ActionBar and swipe which work well.
Acording to action user the class `FragmentA`,`FragmentB`,`FragmentC` show in the scren.

How can I add child fragment without ActionBar and without swipe from `FragmentA` class

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a,container,false);
    }
}
```

so from `FragmentA` I will have

-- FragmentAA
-- FragmentAB

Many Thanks For any help.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    ViewPager viewPager=null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        viewPager= (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        final ActionBar actionBar=getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        addTabs(actionBar);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int i, float v, int i2) {
               }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int i) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(i);
              }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {

            }
        });

        }
    private void addTabs(ActionBar actionBar)
    {
        ActionBar.Tab tab1=actionBar.newTab();
        tab1.setText("Tab 1");
        tab1.setTabListener(this);

        ActionBar.Tab tab2=actionBar.newTab();
        tab2.setText("Tab 2");
        tab2.setTabListener(this);

        ActionBar.Tab tab3=actionBar.newTab();
        tab3.setText("Tab 3");
        tab3.setTabListener(this);

        actionBar.addTab(tab1);
        actionBar.addTab(tab2);
        actionBar.addTab(tab3);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }
}

class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter
{

    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        Fragment fragment=null;
        if(i==0)
        {
            fragment=new FragmentA();
        }
        if(i==1)
        {
            fragment=new FragmentB();
        }
        if(i==2)
        {
            fragment=new FragmentC();
        }
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

Comment: you mean, outside of the viewpager?

Comment: yes, Did I just need to add code to `FragmentA oncreate` `if (savedInstanceState == null){
           mSubFragment = new SubFragment();

           //add child fragment
           getChildFragmentManager()
                   .beginTransaction()
                   .add(R.id.fragment_sub, mSubFragment, false)
                   .commit();
        }`

Comment: yes exactly, that would insert the fragment into the container you specify. Be sure to have a proper container with layoutparams, etc, and it should work perfectly.